# Angular theme is not compiling in application

Tags: angular-material

Here, I am trying to use angular material in my application for better UI.
In style.css file, i have imported the prebuilt theme from angular material.
But when i am trying to compile it gives me an error.

This is my style.css file,

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indogo-pink.css";
```

This is error i am getting,

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indogo-pink.css' in 'C:\Users\MIL001\Webeclipse\AngularMaterialDemo\src'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css 3:10-203
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/styles.css
```

what should i do, please suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix your issue, you need to make sure that the theme is imported in the `styles.css` file (it's located in the `src` folder). Then change your import with the following one `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` as you have misspelled the `indigo` word (you wrote *indogo*)

I hope I helped you :)